# How to Know if array has same letters as string

Tags: javascript, arrays

so what I have been trying to acheive is that if I iterate over `arr` and `string` and if they have the same letters then some action should be perfomed, for example - `if ("both string and array have the same letters"){ "some action" }`

```
const word = "hello";

const arr = ["o", "l", "e", "h"];
```

Comment: arr.every(e => word.includes(e))

Comment: Use Set with array.every()

Comment: Define 'same letters' - does every character of `word` have to be in `arr`, and every character in `arr` have to be in `word`? Or just in one direction?

Comment: this is quite a fun little problem. Why ask stackoverflow for some one-liner when you could write a clever little algorithm yourself!

Answer (score 1):

```
const word = "hello";
const arr = ["o", "l", "e", "h"];

const uWord = [...new Set(word)].sort().join()
const uArr = [...new Set(arr)].sort().join()

if (uWord === uArr) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I'd argue it's the shortest and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is with Linear time O(n).  Check whether both items has same chars and same chars count.

```js
const isMatch = (arr, word, track = {}) => {
  arr.forEach((char) => (track[char] = (track[char] ?? 0) + 1));
  [...word].forEach((char) => (track[char] = (track[char] ?? 0) - 1));
  return !Object.values(track).some((val) => val < 0);
};


console.log(isMatch(["o", "l", "e", "h"], "hello"));
console.log(isMatch(["o", "l", "e", "h", "l"], "hello"));
console.log(isMatch(["o", "o"], "lo"));
```